# How to solve the undefined value of variable in react component?

Tags: reactjs

i want to solve the error of getting ¨'cannot read property x of undefined'

what i am trying to do?
i have  a react component and within that on mount i get the position and send it as props to child component...in doing so i getting cannot read property x of undefined.

Below is my code,

```
export class ParentComponent extends React.PureComponent {
     constructor(props) {
         super(props);
     }

     componentDidMount() {
         this.apply_position();
     }

     get_positioning = (rect, alignment) => {
         switch(alignment) {
             case 'left':
                 return {x: rect.left, y: rect.top + (rect.height / 2)};
             case 'top':
                 return {x: rect.left + (rect.width / 2) , y: rect.top};
             case 'bottom':
                 return {x: rect.left + (rect.width / 2), y: rect.bottom};
             case 'right':
                 return {x: rect.right + (this.props.start_offset || 0), y:rect.top + (rect.height / 
                 2)};
             default:
                 return {x: (rect.left + rect.width / 2), y: rect.top + (rect.height / 2) + 
                 (this.props.end_offset || 0)};
         }
     }

     apply_position = () => {
         const start_anchor_rect = this.props.start_anchor_element && 
         this.props.start_anchor_element.getBoundingClientRect();
         if (this.props.end_anchor_element) {
             this.start_position = this.get_positioning(start_anchor_rect, 
             this.props.start_anchor_alignment);
             const end_anchor_rect = this.props.end_anchor_element.getBoundingClientRect();
             this.end_position = this.get_positioning(end_anchor_rect);
         }
     }

     render() {
         const {start_selector, end_selector, start_offset, end_offset, start_anchor_alignment} = 
         this.props;

         return (
             <ChildComponent
                 end_x={this.end_position.x}
                 end_y={this.end_position.y}
                 start_x={this.start_position.x}
                 start_y={this.start_position.y}
              />
         );
     }
 }
```

I think before calculating x value for end_position or start_position on the first render it gets this error. how can i check if start_position and end_position have some value then render or something like that. could someone help me with this. thanks.

Comment: Please check before you calculate it

Comment: That error means you're trying to access an entity in an object which is undefined. Something like `myObj.x` when `myObj` is undefined. Do a `console.log` inside your render for start_position and end_position.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not storing the computation of `start_position` and `end_position`.

You will have to initialize them in the constructor.

```
constructor(props) {
  super(props);
  this.state = {
    start_position: 0,
    end_position: 0
  }
}
```

Set this values in your `get_positioning` function using `setState` api of React.

Then you can use them as `this.state.start_position` and `this.state.end_position`.

Also, you are not returning from `apply_position` function. Return a value if you do not want to use the state and directly compute while passing as prop in `<ChildComponent/>`

You can do the above as follows :

```
 apply_position = () => {
     // ... exisiting computation of start_position and end_position.

     return { start_position, end_position }
     }
 }
```

Then in your render function, you can just check for the value returned from apply_position function and use them in props.

```
 render() {
     let { start_position, end_position } = apply_position();

     return (
         <ChildComponent
             end_x={end_position.x}
             end_y={end_position.y}
             start_x={start_position.x}
             start_y={start_position.y}
          />
     );
```

If there are other properties in your `start_position` and `end_position`, then you must ensure that `x` and `y` properties exist in them. 
Else it will throw undefined error.

Comment: thanks could you update your answer with returning values instead of using state.

Comment: @someuser2491 Updated.